# hi after migrating 1.9 to 2.1.8 advanced_pricing_button error

Tags: product, configurable-product, product-attribute

after **migrating** from **1.9.3 to 2.1.8** show me below error just when i want to edit old products and i changed configuration parameter and does not change anything
and show below error

```
The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "advanced_pricing_button" component.
```

for example i change 
this

```
 'config' => $visibilityConfig,
```

to

```
'config' => ['componentType'=>'container',$visibilityConfig],
```

but not solved

Comment: i solved my problem with change attribute_set in sql query to default